# Glassfish - missing package=org.apache.commons.collections

Tags: java, plugins, netbeans, maven

I'm developing OSGI bundle which uses RingFIFOBuffer from the package org.apache.commons.collections

This is the souce code of the bundle:

```
package org.DX_57.osgi.NB_27.impl;

import org.apache.commons.collections.Buffer;
import org.apache.commons.collections.BufferUtils;
import org.apache.commons.collections.buffer.CircularFifoBuffer;

public class NetworkBuffer {

    public NetworkBuffer(){
    }

    Buffer fifo = (Buffer) BufferUtils.synchronizedBuffer(new CircularFifoBuffer(200));

    public String GetString(){        
        String Value = (String) fifo.get();        
       // fifo.remove(Value);                
        return Value;
    }

    public void InsertString(String Value){                
        fifo.add(Value);
       // fifo.remove("3");        

    }

    public String ClearBuffer(){        
        fifo.clear();        
        return "0";
    }

    public int BufferSize(){
        int Size = fifo.size();
        return Size;
    }

    public boolean ClearElement(String Value){
        boolean remove = fifo.remove(Value);
        return remove;
    }    

}
```

This is the POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.DX_57.osgi.NB_27</groupId>
        <artifactId>NB_27</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>NB_27-impl</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>NB_27-impl</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${pom.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>NB_27-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Import-Package>${pom.groupId}.api, org.osgi.framework, org.apache.commons.collections, org.apache.commons.collections.buffer</Import-Package>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Activator>${pom.groupId}.impl.NetworkBridgeApp</Bundle-Activator>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <groupId>org.DX_57.osgi.NB_27</groupId>
</project>
```

I can successfully compile the OSGI bundle with Netbeans but when I try to deploy the bundle on Glassfish I get this error:

```
[337]: Unable to resolve 337.0: missing requirement [337.0] package; (package=org.apache.commons.collections)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle NB_27-impl [337]: Unable to resolve 337.0: missing requirement [337.0] package; (package=org.apache.commons.collections)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3443)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1727)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:922)
    at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.startBundle(OSGiDeployedBundle.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.resume(OSGiDeployedBundle.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.start(OSGiDeployedBundle.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:384)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:202)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:184)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]
```

I added these lines into the POM file of the bundle:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

But still the package `org.apache.commons.collections` is not found. Any idea what causes this problem?

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question, but other dependencies was asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352710/osgi-missing-requirement-error).
Basically you're missing a module that's exporting commons-collection som either embed it or create a model that exports it (download and install?).